# Automatically send an email listing all unread emails

Tags: linux, email, imap

I have an email account that I manage with some SIEVE rules to dispatch and flag each newly received emails in different folders.

I'm looking for a way to automatically send an email listing all emails received a day (each day) that I have not read, lot of them already dispatched in folders. The list should at least contain folder names and objects of each unseen emails.

I found a lot of examples using a proprietary software from Microsoft (Power automate), but I'm using GNU/Linux (voidlinux), and I'm looking for something easily maintainable.

I use a webmail that can't offer a lot of possibilities for this project so it will be probably using another way, I'm really open to any idea (my last search let me think of a cronjob with some openssl commands, but I don't find any relevant source to know how to start).

EDIT:
I'm trying to use openssl, this is what I can do until now, step by step, with a specific folder :

`openssl s_client -starttls imap -connect imap.server.com:143 -quiet`

Once connected

```
A01 LOGIN login "password"
A02 EXAMINE "aSpecificFolder"
A03 SEARCH UNSEEN
A04 FETCH 1:* (BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT FROM)])
```

Unfortunately, If A02 part list 1 unseen email on 5 in the folder (it's true), the A03 list the numbers 1 2 3 5 (I don't know what it refers to. Probably the IDs of emails in this folder, but why 4 emails instead of 1 unseen as expected, or even 5 in case it lists all emails) and the A04 fetch the info for 5 emails (the whole folder, so)...

Comment: `unseen emails` ... do you mean unread emails?

Comment: A *very* vague outline of how I'd attempt it, depending on mail application: 1. As each msg arrives, add from and subj to a text file. 2. cron job to mail the text file, then pause, then delete it.

Comment: @jsotola yes, I mean unread emails. IMAP use the term UNSEEN.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik
The script doesn't need to be executed each time an email arrive.
Until now, I'm trying openssl, step by step, with a specific folder. I use this :
```
openssl s_client -starttls imap -connect imap.server.com:143 -quiet
```
Once connected
```
A01 LOGIN login "password"
A02 EXAMINE "aSpecificFolder"
A03 SEARCH UNSEEN
A04 FETCH 1:* (BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT FROM)])
```
Unfortunately, If A02 part list 1 unseen email on 5 in the folder, the A03 list the numbers 1 2 3 5 (?) and the A04 fetch the informations for 5 emails (the whole folder, so)...